# speed up date transformation the data.table way

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large table of contract dates. In my final table I want to have a single row for every month a contract is active. Problem is the speed of my current solution. Is there a faster way to achieve this? (I have more than 1 Mio ID's with different contract runtimes and it takes several minutes. I suspect cbind?!)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=c(123, 345),
             start=c(as.IDate("2013-01-01"), as.IDate("2012-01-01")),
             end=c(as.IDate("2013-04-01"),as.IDate("2012-02-01") ))

dt[, cbind(.SD, seq(start, end, by="month")), by=id]

    id      start        end         V2
1: 123 2013-01-01 2013-04-01 2013-01-01
2: 123 2013-01-01 2013-04-01 2013-02-01
3: 123 2013-01-01 2013-04-01 2013-03-01
4: 123 2013-01-01 2013-04-01 2013-04-01
5: 345 2012-01-01 2012-02-01 2012-01-01
6: 345 2012-01-01 2012-02-01 2012-02-01
```

Comment: Have you tried just generating the months using `dt[, seq(start, end, by="month"), by=id]` and then joining it with the original data?

Answer (score 3):

First thoughts: A couple of tweaks I could think of.

- First, I'd use `seq.int` instead of `seq`, the latter being a *S3-generic* would take some time for dispatch, and that could be costly on a million groups.
- Second, I'd use `1.9.3` (which is almost complete and should be pushed to CRAN soon) where quite a few enhancements are made.
- Third, I'd use `c(.SD, seq.int(start, end, by="month"))` in `j` - this is internally optimised in `1.9.3`, and therefore would be much faster.

In essence, try this on 1.9.3:

```
dt[, c(.SD, seq.int(start, end, by="month")), by=id]
```

Of course this is still running on a million groups, and therefore might still be slower (even though faster than your previous answer). Still, I'd be curious to know the speed-up here (if at all).

But the *real* problem here is that we're evaluating `j-expression` for *each group*, and you've got a million of'em. What would be ideal is if `seq.int`'s `from` and `to` arguments were capable of handling inputs of length > 1. But, most likely, you'll have to write your own C/C++ code to get there.